# category.php not showing in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am running wordpress 4.2 in a local machine with wampserver64 at this point everything its ok, im just trying to create a wordpress template, I have index.php, header.php, footer.php, sidebar.php, style.css, single.php, functions.php and category.php

but the problem comes when i click on a post category link I get http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/category/music/ i get file not found instead of localhost/wordpress/category/music/ with the post with that category.

I have the loop on category.php but its not loading category.php I dont know why,it seems that wordpress is trying to find the categories in index.php and not from `category.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try these solution if it helps

1) change your permalink structure to default just to check

**or**

2) create a `.htaccess` file on root and insert this code

your .htacces file looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /name_of_your_wordpress_installation_folder/
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Hi @ris, i already have that file:
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/ [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: you should try with change the permalink structure once.

Comment: Sorry, but how do i do that? im new in wordpress templates. Thank you for the reply :D

Comment: does your category page goes blank? if it is you might need to debug category.php file..

Comment: you can change permalink structure from backend .

Comment: it does not load category.php, apparently it tries to search the categories in index.php and not from category.php. localhost/wordpress/index.php/category/category_name and not displaying even the blank page, i will try change the permalink in the dashboard like ris said and ill post the result here. thanks for the reply :D

Comment: Thank you very much!! it worked!, just changing the permalink from wp dashboard to default and now loads the category.php but now i have another problem but i will ask that in another question. :'D